# Coluna index no datatables laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-datatables, lado-do-servidor

Quando não carregava os dados dinamicamente para a tabela utilizava dessa forma para criar a coluna index: https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

```
 t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
    t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    } );
} ).draw();
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/umn75pj1/

Porém, agora que estou carregando a tabela dinamicamente server-side não funciona adequadamente. Fica sempre de 1 a 5. Se aumento resultados por página some o index.

Tentei utilizar dessa forma e também não tive êxito:

```
t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
    cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    t.cell(cell).invalidate('dom');
} ); } ).draw();
```

Estou estudando jquery, laravel e o uso server-side do datatables ainda. Não sei como resolver isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir fazer funcionar.

Para quem passar pelo mesmo problema que esse eu resolvi utilizando page.info(), fazendo o produto do valor da quantidade de itens a serem exibidos e o número da página atual: **page.info().page * page.info().length**.

```
tabela.on('draw.dt', function() {
    tabela.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied'}).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = tabela.page.info().page * tabela.page.info().length + i + 1;  
    });
}).draw();
```